# Export functions in netlogo yielding error message

Tags: netlogo

I run the following code to export essentials during Netlogo 6.0 simulations in order to create a file organization structure for data output:

```
export-output (word "levy-output" date-and-time ".csv")
export-world (word "levy-input" date-and-time ".csv")
export-interface (word "levy-interface" date-and-time ".csv")
export-all-plots (word "levy-plots " date-and-time ".csv")
```

I got the following error messages respectively:

```
error (IllegalStateException)
 while observer running EXPORT-OUTPUT
  called by procedure CORRELATED-RANDOM-WALK
  called by Button 'Correlated-Random-Walk'

export-world: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
error while observer running EXPORT-WORLD
  called by procedure CORRELATED-RANDOM-WALK
  called by Button 'Correlated-Random-Walk'

error (IllegalStateException)
 while observer running EXPORT-INTERFACE
  called by procedure CORRELATED-RANDOM-WALK
  called by Button 'Correlated-Random-Walk'

error (IllegalStateException)
 while observer running EXPORT-ALL-PLOTS
  called by procedure CORRELATED-RANDOM-WALK
  called by Button 'Correlated-Random-Walk'
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax that I am using?

Comment: `date-and-time` is presumably returning a string containing a character that is illegal in pathnames on your operating system — perhaps a colon?

Comment: The fact that you get `IllegalStateException` instead of a proper error message for most of these seems like a bug in NetLogo.